# How can I open an .flp file?

Tags: filesystems

For context, opening it with notepad on Windows 10 results in gibberish, except a heading that says "PARSONS TECHNOLOGY RESOURCE DATA FILE". It automatically uses ANSI format, with Unix line feeds.

So far I've tried opening it with VLC Media Player, 7-Zip, Gimp, even Audacity, although it's supposed to be a scan of a document.

Comment: https://filext.com/file-extension/FLP

Comment: In most cases it has to opened by the software that created it.

Comment: PARSONS TECHNOLOGY==Its an  very old and defunct company now.